# How to color cells in a pandas dataframe based on a given condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df

```
            ID     col1      col2      col3              
             1       x        y          z
  df1 =      2       a        b          x
             3       y        t          r
```

and another df as

```
             ID           col   
   df2 =      1        [x,y,c,d,z]
              2        [g,a,x,n,c]
              3        [g,j,h]
```

Now I want to iterate over every ID in df2 and check if the corresponding values in "col" of that ID is present in any of the column in df1 for the same ID. If the value is present I want to colour that cell in df1.

Expected Output:

```
            ID     col1                            col2                             col3              
             1    <p style="color:red;">x</p>   <p style="color:red;">y</p>    <p style="color:red;">z</p> 
  df1 =      2    <p style="color:red;">a</p>      b                           <p style="color:red;">x</p>
             3       g                             j                            h
```

Kindly help.

Comment: Have you tried anything to get the expected output? Any specific problems or errors you get?

Comment: hint: `df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : color` , try with this